# tableau search text within entire data

Tags: search, text, tableau-api

I have a tabular data with multiple text columns. I would like to build a capability where a user can enter any word and Tableau will search that word across all columns and rows and then return all rows that contain that word. How could I build the same capability?

One thing that came to my mind is as below -

if my data is like this -

```
name    hobby
abc xy  running, painting
dc zb   swimming, cooking
```

then create a new column, which would have each unique word in the row and repeat each row for each unique word (in that row). And then apply a filter on the new column

```
name    hobby                   each word
abc xy  running, painting   abc
abc xy  running, painting   xy
abc xy  running, painting   running
abc xy  running, painting   painting
dc zb   swimming, cooking   dc
dc zb   swimming, cooking   zb
dc zb   swimming, cooking   swimming
dc zb   swimming, cooking   cooking
```

But that would be very inefficient when my data is too big

Is there any alternate way?

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it with a pivot table in tableau.

- Select filed

[image]

- Right click and select pivot

[image]

- It will look like this

[image]

Comment: how would this fix my search problem? Looking at your last screenshot, i feel that you are showing a way to put entire data in a single column....but if a cell has two values, example - swimming, cooking - how would i implement a search?

Comment: Moreover, if I have many rows and columns then the single column would have a lot of rows..my concern is that huge number of rows would make Tableau slow

Comment: @Ni_Tempe I have tried but this only option that I found. You have to use other tools like R and Python to clean your data for visualization.